# how to use regex in django.db.models.query.values() method

Tags: python, django, database, string

I am trying to get values from django.db.models.query, but I wanna use something like `latest_stichtag_values.values("buchung__" + any character)`, example of it in normal python regex would be like `r"^[buchung__]\w*"`, which matches

```
buchung__
buchung__fdsaf
buchung__ddd
```

But not

```
asss_buchung__
aaaa
```

So, my question is how can use it in `latest_stichtag_values.values("buchung__" + any character)`

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

probably you can read about DJANGO ORM.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet
What do this code:

```
latest_stichtag_values.values("buchung__" + any character)
```

This code returns you whole column with name str("buchung__" + any character)

i can imagine, you want made filter and after get values of result

```
latest_stichtag_values.filter('buchung__like'=any_character).values_list('buchung')
```

By the way. Try to avoid German language in names of vars.
A am from Austria, but we have developers from whole world. And it is a little bit disrespectful, if somebody use not englisch. And it seems strange:
latest_stichtag (German) + values (Englisch).

Comment: thank you for your response, I did already the filtering part now I wanna do something like ```list(latest_stichtag_values.values( "buchung__" + filter_top))``` and filter_top could be something like kunde, konzern,  and os on, but I don't know what are they exactly, that's I am trying to do something like ```r"^[buchung__]\w*"```